# How to control gap between vehicles in SUMO at high speed?

Tags: sumo

I am doing some simulation in SUMO at high speed 100 Km/h, the space between vehicles is large and i would like to narrow. I think this space is coming because of the high speed. Does there exist any command to control the maximum Gap between vehicles in SUMO same as it exist for the minimum gap "minGap.

Answer (score 0):

This gap is controlled by the time gap parameter tau which can be modified just like the minGap (but has seconds as unit). The default is 1 and commonly used values for automated driving are 0.8 or 0.5 but even down to 0.2. You need to make sure though that your simulation step size (--step-length) is at most the time gap.